# JTable - Updating JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I made a table to bold data from `Arraylist`, but if I delete that data, I would want to the table update and debold the cells that were bolded from the Arraylist. How would I go about doing this? or close that instance of the class from another class

Comment: Please consider add your code. Or even better post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) recreating your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Changes to the data should be done in the TableModel. When you change the data you then invoke:

```
fireTableCellUpdated(...)
```

to notify the table of the change so it can repaint itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can write something like this ,

```
 recordDeleted: function (event, data) {
            //something to debold the cells



         },
```